# normalize image with opencv in c++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing

I have a TfLite model that takes a standardized float32 image as an input, the pixel range should convert from the [0~255] to [-1~1] I wrote a demo function but it didn't work. I couldn't set the color value back to the image;
How can I set the color back to the "des" image? and Is there a better way to do that?

this is my demo code

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>

void standardize(cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &des)
{
    cv::Vec3b  src_color,des_color;
    for(int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++)
        {
            src_color =  src.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(j,i));                        
            des_color =  des.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(j,i));
            des_color[0] = ((int) src_color[0] -127.5 ) / 127.5 ;
            des_color[1] = ((int) src_color[1] -127.5 ) / 127.5 ;
            des_color[2] = ((int) src_color[2] -127.5 ) / 127.5 ;
            
            des.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(j,i)) = des_color ;
            
            std::cout <<  (int) src_color[0]   << std::endl;                          
            std::cout << ((int) src_color[0] -127.5 ) / 127.5  << std::endl;          
            std::cout << (int) des.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(j,i))[0] << std::endl; 
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat src, des;
    // src ---> CV_8UC3 
    src = cv::imread("/test.jpg");
    // copy to take the same size
    src.copyTo(des);
    // des ----> CV_32FC3
    src.convertTo(des, CV_32FC3);
    standardize(src,des);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "normalize", not "standardize"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please do not write for loops. instead:

```
src.convertTo(dst, CV_32F);
dst -= 127;
dst /= 255; // EDIT
```

Comment: I try but it didn't work. didn't give an error either

Comment: please, -- "didnt work" NEVER worked for anyone as an explanation

Comment: sorry about that, I add the two lines that you wrote and used the standardize function for printing the value only
this is from the src [182, 202, 237]
and this from the dst [237, 237, 63] the output still bigger than 1

Comment: you should not have a 'standardize()' function any more ;)

Comment: how can I see the output so I can be sure? :)

Comment: `cout << dst << endl;` (you can print out whole Mat's)

Comment: I'm still getting outputs bigger than "one"  1.6705884, 1.9607844, 0.52941179, 1.6784315, 1.9529413, 0.52156866, 1.6627452, 1.9529413, 0.49803925, 1.647059, 1.9215688, 0.45098042, 1.6000001, 1.8901962, 0.42745101, 1.5843139, 1.8588237]                           any idea why?

Comment: src.convertTo(dst, CV_32F, 1./255.0 , 0 ); solve it

Comment: apologies, wrong scale factor (see edit). and unfortunately, `convertTo()` subtracts *after* the division (wrong order)